# Is there a polytope with face poset given by the lattice of (unordered) partitions?

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, set-partition, polytopes

The permutohedron has as it's face poset the lattice of ordered set partitions (I've also seen this called the lattice of set compositions). I'm wondering if there is a polytope with face poset given by the lattice of set partitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set.

Comment: Just thinking through the lattice, my guess is that said polytope would be nothing other than the $n$-simplex where $n$ is the number of elements in the set. For instance, the 4-simplex has 5 cells, 10 faces, 10 edges, and 5 vertices. Correspondingly, a set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ has 5 subsets of one element, 10 subsets of two elements, 10 subsets of three elements, and five subsets of four elements.

Comment: @Semiclassical The OP is asking about the lattice of set partitions ordered by refinement, not the lattice of subsets ordered by inclusion (for that the polytope is the unit hypercube, btw). Here is  [Piesk's visualization](https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2015/06/15/lattice-of-partitions/) of the partition lattice for $n=4$. In principle, poset polytope exists for any lattice, see [Pegel, Polyhedral Geometry of Posets](https://d-nb.info/115083384X/34).

Comment: @Conifold Could you cite a specific place in Pegel's text where this is said? It is 157 pages long...

Comment: Thanks for the reference! However your statement "In principle, poset polytope exists for any lattice..." seems to contradict the answer below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lattice of partitions of an $n$-element set fails the diamond property (if $n \ge 3$), so according to [this Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope#Formal_definition) it is not (even) an abstract polytope.

The diamond property says that if the ranks of two faces $a>b$ differ by 2, then there are exactly 2 faces strictly between $a$ and $b$.

In the partition lattice of $3$ elements ($1, 2, 3$) the diamond property fails between  the rank-$2$ face $a=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ and the rank-$0$ face $b=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$, since strictly between them there are *three* faces, the two-block partitions. You can easily generalize this to bigger partition lattices.

As an example of the diamond property in geometric terms, in a three-dimensional polytope: (i) any edge is incident with exactly two faces; (ii) a vertex of a face is incident with exactly two edges of that face.

With $n=2$ the partition lattice has just two elements, $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\}\}$, and in this case you do get a polytope (a single point).